# Not working correctly the characterRange on iOS16

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16

I got the bug on iOS16 like below.

I'm using this blow code to check character position.

```
 let end = caption.characterRange(at: CGPoint(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.maxY))?.end
```

I got the print log using the above code on iOS15.5.

```
Optional(<_UITextKitTextPosition: 0x60000216e1e0> (153B))
```

But when I run on the iOS16.0 simulator, I got this print log.

```
Optional(<_UITextKitTextPosition: 0x6000038a9240> (573F))
```

Is it os bug? Do you have any information about iOS16?